# Cannot find head tag in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, xml, local.xml

I want to add a bug herd javascript extension in head tag of my magento 2.1 store but unable to find the `<head>` tag. i searched for the local xml but it was not there. How to locate this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is on : 
/app/design/frontend/"your_theme_package"/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

Comment: or  on default.xml like this : http://prntscr.com/gyj6b6

Comment: how i will add in the xml file ? i want to add in `script` in this file.

Comment: you find : /app/design/frontend/your_theme/web/js.
add a js file and call it in the head tag

Comment: can you please help how would i call this  in the head tag i cannot see any js example .

Comment: just add a file in the js folder and name it : test.js 
and on the head tag add <script src="js/test.js"/>
like this example http://prntscr.com/gyja88

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67235/discussion-between-magentodeveloper-and-tech-geek).